# Route53 configuration for subdomains for different environments in 123 reg

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, godaddy, hosted

I have a main domain lets call it `example.com`. In aws I have created a hosted zone via pipeline for `test.example.com` and added 4 NS records to 123-reg.com and its working perfectly.

Now I am trying to create a stag environment `stag.example.com` and my pipeline created a new hosted zone for stag.example.com and asking to add different 4 ns records, my question is 123-reg only allows maximum 4 ns records and if i remove the old 4 ns records my test.exmaple.com wont work anymore.
how to configure this properly?

thanks

Comment: If you are using delegated zones for your subdomains, then you only create one record for the delegated zone that contains the 4 name servers. You do not add more name servers (NS resource records) to the parent zone. Edit your question with details including a view of how you are configuring the subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added new load balancer dns record to the same hosted zone created by other environments. This worked for me.